# Why are the maximum X and Y touch coordinates on the Surface Pro is different from native display resolution?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have noticed that the Surface Pro and I believe the Sony Vaio Duo 11 are reporting maximum touch coordinates of 1366x768, which is surprising to me since their native display resolution is 1920x1080.
Does anyone know of a way to find out at runtime what the maximum touch coordinates are? I'm running a DirectX app underneath the XAML, so I have to scale the touch coordinates into my own world coordinates and I cannot do this without knowing what the scale factor is.

Here is the code that I'm running that looks at the touch coordinates:

From DirectXPage.xaml

```
<Grid PointerPressed="OnPointerPressed"></Grid>
```

From DirectXPage.xaml.cpp

```
void DirectXPage::OnPointerPressed(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerRoutedEventArgs^ args)
{
   auto pointerPoint = args->GetCurrentPoint(nullptr);
   // the x value ranges between 0 and 1366
   auto x = pointerPoint->Position.X;
   // the y value ranges between 0 and 768
   auto y = pointerPoint->Position.Y;
}
```

Also, here is a sample project setup that can demonstrate this issue if run on a Surface Pro:
http://andrewgarrison.com/files/TouchTester.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything on XAML side is measured in device independent pixels. Ideally you should never have to worry about actual physical pixels and let winrt do its magic in the background.

If for some season you do need to find you current scale factor you can use [DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayproperties.resolutionscale) and use it to convert DIPs into screen pixels.

Answer (score 1):

> their native display resolution is 1920x1080

That makes the display fit the HD Tablet profile, everything is automatically scaled by 140%.  With of course the opposite un-scaling occurring for any reported touch positions.  You should never get a position beyond 1371,771.  This ensures that any Store app works on any device, regardless of the quality of its display and without the application code having to help, beyond providing bitmaps that still look sharp when the app is rescaled to 140 and 180%.  You should therefore not do anything at all.  It is unclear what problem you are trying to fix.

An excellent article that describes the automatic scaling feature [is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx).

Comment: Is there a way to know if I'm running on a tablet that is using this scaling, because when the same app is run on my dev machine, it reports touch (really mouse) coordinates from 0x0 to 1920x1200.

Comment: The problem is that I have to scale the touch coordinates from screen coordinates into world coordinates, which I cannot do without knowing the max X and Y touch coordinates. I'm using meters as a unit in my game, and if I know the world is 10 meters wide, and the user touched at 1366 pixels, does that mean they are touching at 10 meters, or are they touching at 1366/1920*10 meters?

Comment: You are not doing this right.  If you scale your drawing by 1366/10.0 then you should scale the input by 10.0/1366, the inverse.  Screen resolution is never a factor.